# MVC .NET Core Generar Controlador con vistas utilizando Wizard

Tags: c#, mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hace poco que me introduje al mundo del EntityFramework utilizando un libro de introducción pero al EntityFramework Core 2.0, en uno de los capítulos el autor comienza con un pequeño proyecto utilizando MVC (siguiendo con EF 2.0), y me tropecé con un error que no cubre ese libro, de acuerdo a las indicaciones del autor, los controladores se agregan por medio del wizard y elige la opción que genera también las vistas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto obviamente lleva a la ventana para elegir la clase del modelo y la clase del contexto de datos, pero al confirmar o dar clic en agregar, después de unos segundos, me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensando que el problema sería alguno de los paquetes NuGet que en el libro indica que se instalen, actualice los que necesitaban una actualización, pero no fue el caso, detecte que el problema es al momento de intentar agregar las vistas, ya que al agregarlas manualmente (ya sea utilizando una plantilla en blanco o utilizando uno de los modelos ya creados) me sale el mismo error, en el mensaje se puede ver que dice que se restaure el proyecto, pero no entiendo porque lo pide si el proyecto esta prácticamente en blanco (excepto por los modelos de cada tabla) o en todo caso que es lo que se deba restaurar.

Por mas que he buscado no encuentro alguna solución especifica para este caso y realmente no se que puedo buscar pues ni siquiera se cual es el problema.

Esta es la versión de Visual Studio que estoy utilizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los paquetes NuGet que actualmente están instalados en el proyecto (algunos los indica el autor del libro, otros los instale pues había un par de errores por extensiones de interfaces que no se reconocían):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Pues después de mucho batallar, por fin logre hacerlo funcionar, aunque al final no sé cual pudo haber sido el problema.
Lo que hice (y ya había hecho) fue desinstalar todos los paquetes NuGet, e instalarlos uno por uno eligiendo las versiones 2.0.0 de cada uno (o la menor versión posible si no había 2.0.0), hasta que ya no me aparecieran errores de sintaxis, al finalizar y compilar de nuevo, me mando otro error que pedía actualizar únicamente dos paquetes (EntityFrameworkcore y EntityFrameworkCore.Design) a las versiones 2.0.3, después de compilar correctamente ya me permitió agregar las vistas manualmente y por medio del wizard